# Function of an efficient estimator?

Tags: estimation, mathematical-statistics, umvue

Let $T$ be an efficient estimator for a parameter $\theta$.

- Is $g(T)$ (with $g(·)$ not linear) an efficient estimator for $g(\theta)$?
- Is $g(T)$ an minimum-variance unbiased estimator (UMVUE) for
  $g(\theta)$?